# Блок для аккордеона

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте,Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой блок ?
Пробовал сделать контейнер,в котором делаю обводку,и поместить в контейнер 2 дива (левый и правый),только горизонтальную линию после '-' не получается поставить ,и когда увеличиваю '-' через фонт сайз - то весь блок летит

Comment: Ну покажите Ваши усилия.

Answer (score 1):

считаете что Ваш велосипед будет самый велосипед?
аккордеон есть во всех библиотеках - например [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div><p>1</p></div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div><p>2</p></div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div><p>3</p></div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div><p>4<p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

А [здесь](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_simple_horizontal_accordion.htm) пример горизонтального.

Тире увеличивать через font-size чтобы добиться нужной ширины конечно прикольная идея... :-) Такие идеи приходят обычно после 16-часового рабочего дня - ложитесь спать а завтра нарисуйте тире-картинку :-))

Comment: Меня интересует как сделать именно такой блок как на фото,а не сама реализация аккордеона )

Comment: Да только когда аккордеон открыт мне нужно чтобы был минус,а когда закрыт - плюс,и думаю менять картинку будет не сильно удобно. А можете подсказать как нарисовать такой блок ?
У меня не получается провести черту после тире

Comment: где черту? на рисунке нет черты. 
а картинку поменять что за проблема? ну сделайте через спрайт по крутому если переживаете что долго грузиться будет или что еще :-)
картинку через CSS/спрайт поменять, это круто, топовая практика

Comment: а чтобы увеличить ширину не нужно font-size в максималку тянуть - есть же font-stretch: ultra-condensed;

Answer (score 1):

```css
li{list-style: none;margin-bottom: 10px;}

.line{
  color: #4f92bc;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  display: inline-block;
}
.line div{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.line div:nth-child(1){
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.line div:nth-child(2){
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class='line'>
      <div>-</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='line'>
      <div>-</div>
      <div>Dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class='line'>
      <div>-</div>
      <div>Nisi, voluptatem</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```